# How to generate FFI dependencies before stack builds my project (with nix)?

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, haskell-stack, nix

I have a Haskell + stack + nix project that makes heavy use of FFI code. The problem is that two of the C files that I depend upon have to be *generated* before I can compile my Haskell project at large. These two files are (i) `./cbits/xdg-shell-protocol.c` and (ii) `./include/xdg-shell-protocol.h`.

First, here is the Makefile which can generate these files:

```
WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS=$(shell pkg-config --variable=pkgdatadir wayland-protocols)
WAYLAND_SCANNER=$(shell pkg-config --variable=wayland_scanner wayland-scanner)

# wayland-scanner is a tool which generates C headers and rigging for Wayland
# protocols, which are specified in XML. wlroots requires you to rig these up
# to your build system yourself and provide them in the include path.
xdg-shell-protocol.h:
 $(WAYLAND_SCANNER) server-header \
   $(WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS)/stable/xdg-shell/xdg-shell.xml $@

xdg-shell-protocol.c: xdg-shell-protocol.h
 $(WAYLAND_SCANNER) private-code \
   $(WAYLAND_PROTOCOLS)/stable/xdg-shell/xdg-shell.xml $@
```

Notice that I depend upon the system programs `wayland-protocols` and `wayland-scanner`, both of which are specified in my project's `shell.nix`:

```
buildInputs = with pkgs; [ 
                           # ...
                           # These are bleeding edge so I crafted my own nix expressions:
                           (callPackage ./nix/wayland.nix { } )
                           (callPackage ./nix/wayland-protocols.nix { } )
                           # ...
                        ];
```

And finally notice that I tell Haskell about these files in my `package.yaml`:

```
c-sources:
   - cbits/xdg-shell-protocol.c
include-dirs:
  - include
```

**Question:** How can I make it so that everytime someone runs `stack [--nix] build` (with or without nix), the two files (i) `./cbits/xdg-shell-protocol.c` and (ii) `./include/xdg-shell-protocol.h` are ensured to be up to date?